# How to define REST URIs for a resource?

Tags: http, rest, uri

Lets say I have a collection of applicants that can be accessed via

```
/applicants
```

An applicant can be uniquely identified two different ways: by ssn or by an id number.

How would I specify my `GET`s for a specific applicant?

Typically for unique identifiers I would do

```
/applicants/{id}
```

but in this case I have two different unique identifiers.  Any suggestions on the proper way of handling this.

It seems incorrect to do something like

```
/applicants/{id}
/applicants/ssn/{ssn}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being *unique* and being an *identifier* are two different concepts. The identifier (i.e. `id`) would be more appropriate for identifying and locating the resource via URI, because:

1. *You* are (probably) in complete control of the id and its lifecycle.
2. While SSN may be unique today, the government could change the way SSNs work tomorrow. I myself don't like coupling my internal identifiers to external sources.

To me, SSN seems like more a queryable property than a resource identifier, e.g.:

```
# Searches for applicants with the provided ssn
GET /applicants?ssn=000-00-0000
```

Comment: Would you consider it to still be appropriate to return a 404 when using a queryable property?

Comment: Depends on what your `/applicants` normally responds with. Normally I'd expect it to respond with something like a list of application resources that matched the query string, and if there were no matches, just an empty list. I wouldn't expect it to return a 404 in this case.

Comment: Ok thanks. /applicants normally does return an empty list.  But in the case of ?ssn= I think I will return the 404.  For ?lastName= or other non-unique identifiers I think I will go with the empty list.  Thanks for the input.  :D

Comment: @Mike - I'd advise against that - by returning a 404 you're saying that the `/applicants` resource wasn't found, but in actuality it still does exist. Some clients may see that as an indication that they shouldn't make further queries to the resource, or that they have a bug. Plus, conditionally returning a 404 vs. a list depending on the query parameters makes it difficult for clients to code to the API, since it's inconsistent. I'd just make your clients search for the SSN and if the list is empty, do what they'd normally do if it wasn't found.